# I'm trying to call a jquery script from asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

a snippet from my aspx front end code

```
asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl = "~/Scripts/toggleit.js" 

toggleit.js:

$(document).ready(function () {

   $('#Div52').toggle();

});
```

When I run the menuitem it brings up several windows asking me if its secure to run this script? (don't know why it wouldn't be its in my project...)

next it gives off a funky error

`'document' is undefined line 1`

why give NavigateUrl method the ability to run "Scripts" if you can't run jquery scripts?

Comment: in the bundle do you  know .net?

Comment: You can call a function in `NavigateUrl` but not a js file.

Comment: good answer but not a solution, how can I toggle the visibility of a div tag using a MenuItem, if you say you can't do something then how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you use `javascript:myFunctionName();` in anchor tags, but I don't think it will work from ASP Menu Item. I have an inelegant solution.

Wire your navigation menu's click event up to this function

```
public void NavigationMenu_Click(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.Value == "SelfReport")
    {
        // call RegisterClientStartupScript(); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx
    }
}
```

There will be a postback.

A better solution would be to hook the event up on the jQuery side based on the title of the menu item. But I'll leave that answer to someone that's better with jQuery than me.

Comment: ok tried that but now how do I make a div tag on my Default.aspx page become visible, the function is in the site.master.vb page?

Comment: You should tag your question as VB.NET if you're using that language. Your content pages will be merged with your master page upon rendering to the client. So in `RegisterClientStartupScript()` you just call your JavaScript function. When the postback completes, the JavaScript function will execute.